ERC20 Token Basescan | value in $ Not Showing
I created an ERC20 token on base, and added 10$ liquidity to it today.
But when I send it to my wallet, metmask,trust wallet, or basescan.org shows 0$ when its actually 1$ / token on dextools.
With huge Supply
Metamask Swap (https://i.sstatic.net/v80PpMTo.png)
Metamask Swap 2 (https://i.sstatic.net/Jf1jOP52.png)
i don't want it to swap i just want it to show the value of the token
tried waiting for 2 hours, re import multiple times , nothing worked

Maybe the token not being recognized or indexed by the price tracking services used by MetaMask, Trust Wallet, or other wallet interfaces.
